# How do you extend a library created variable in onvif python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-onvif

onvif python will create base variables from WSDL but not the optional elements. How do I add the optional variables to the existing definition?

as in a = create(sometype)

This defines the elements a.b and a.c.

I need to add elements a.c.d, a.c.e.g and a.c.e.h.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide your code.

Comment: Lots and lots of things.

Comment: Please post one example of something you tried in your question.

Comment: I'm not asking for a critique of things that did not work, I'm asking for an example of something that does work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: It depends on what the existing variable is.

The longer answer: Since the existing variable is defined by a third party library with little to no visibility, run the code under a debugger that will tell you what the existing variable is, e.g, list, dict, etc. From that information look in the python documentation if you are not familiar with that type of variable.